# How to overwrite beta APK with a new version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My app is not yet published. I have a beta APK that was uploaded September 28. Today I want to upload a new one, the upload goes fine, but it never shows that the current APK is updated. No matter what I do, I never see my new uploaded version.

What can't I upload my new APK and overwrite the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted support and they said it is actually a bug that they are working to fix.

Answer (score -3):

You need to change the "VersionCode" in Manifest file and then gen the apk. 
Upload it, will work.
Update the version code below:

android:versionCode="2"    >>>>>>>either to 3 or 4